# How do I determine the term frequency of the terms in each document?

Tags: java, frequency

I'm building an inverted index, but I can't seem to get the correct frequencies when I check the database. I read everywhere that you should use a `HashMap`, but I'm not quite sure if this is the correct method of doing so. Any ideas?

```
public class Tokenize {

    public static void createIndex() throws Exception{
        
        ArrayList<Dokument> dok = new QueryHandler().getDokuments();
        ArrayList<String> queries = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> queries2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> frek = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        
        for(int d = 0; d < dok.size(); d++){
            String token = "";
            int frekvens = 0;
            
            
            try{
                
                Dokument document = dok.get(d);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(document.dokument());
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    
                    
                    token = st.nextToken();
                    token.replaceAll("[']", "");
                    token.replaceAll("[,]", "");
                    token.replaceAll("[)]", "");
                    token.replaceAll("[(]", "");
                    token.replaceAll("[.]", "");
                    frekvens ++;
                    frek.put(token, frekvens);
                    
                
                        queries.add("INSERT IGNORE INTO termindeks (docID, term) values ("+document.docID()+", '"+token+"')");
                        queries2.add("INSERT IGNORE INTO invertedindeks (term, docID, termfrekvens) values ('"+token+"', "+document.docID()+", "+ frekvens+")");
                                        
                            
                }
            }
            

            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(token);
            }
        }
        
        String[] ffs = new String[queries.size()];
        ffs = queries.toArray(ffs);
        getDB().runQueriesIgnoreException(queries.toArray(ffs));
        
        String[] ffs2 = new String[queries2.size()];
        ffs2 = queries2.toArray(ffs2);
        getDB().runQueriesIgnoreException(queries2.toArray(ffs2));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the value for the token first, increment it and put it again.

Like this in your loop:

```
Integer frekvens = frek.get(token); //remove the other frekvens as it's not needed - or find a better name for this one ;)
if( frekvens == null ) { frekvens = 0 };
frekvens++;
frek.put(token, frekvens);
```

Comment: +1 Totally forgot that the get() could return a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct but as far as I see, you don't make correct use of the `HashMap`. You have to get the value associated with the key, i.e.

```
Integer i = map.get(token);
i += 1;
map.put(token, i);
```

**EDIT**

Another option would be to use an `AtomicInteger` instead of an `Integer` because `AtomicInteger`s are mutable.

```
Map<String, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();    
map.get(token).getAndIncrement();
```